# Cohomology $H(X^{(p)}, \mathbb Q_{\ell})$ of the Frobenius twist of a variety over a finite field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, etale-cohomology

Let $X$ be a quasi-projective variety over a finite field $\mathbb F_q$ where $q$ is a power of a prime $p$. Let $\ell$ be a prime number different from $p$. We have the relative Frobenius morphism
$$\mathcal F: X \to X^{(p)},$$
as defined for instance in the stack project [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0CC6).

How do the cohomology groups $H^i(X^{(p)} \times \overline{\mathbb F_p}, \mathbb Q_{\ell})$ compare with $H^i(X\times \overline{\mathbb F_p}, \mathbb Q_{\ell})$?